# EF 6 Code-Based Migration: Add not null property to existing entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I want to add a not-null, foreing key column to an existing table.

> Environment: EF 6,Code-First, Code-Based Migration

```
//Code from Migration class for new entity Currency
CreateTable("dbo.Currency",
                c => new
                    {
                        CurrencyID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Code = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 3, fixedLength: true, unicode: false),
                        Denomination = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50, unicode: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.CurrencyID);

AddColumn("dbo.Collection", "CurrencyID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

//Code from Seed() method in Configuration class 
context.Currencies.AddOrUpdate(
    new Currency
    {
        Code = "USD",
        Denomination = "Dollar"
    }
);

//Here i get an exception. Collection is the existing table
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( "update collection set CurrencyID = 1 );
```

Exception message:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Collection_dbo.Currency_CurrencyID". The conflict occurred in
>   table "dbo.Currency", column 'CurrencyID'.

Comment: I would probably just do the creation of the currency in SQL.  Im guessing the AddOrUpdate isn't being committed to the DB

Comment: @Thewads, I think that would break the Code-First workflow and i will be into problem soon.

Comment: well put it this way, your migrations run before your seeder, so if you aren't putting in your currency until the seeder, this won't work

Comment: Excactly @Thewads, that is the problem that i currently have.

Comment: So, why don't you just do the updating of the collection table in your seeder? or are you putting data into it before seeding?

Comment: @Thewads, that is what i'm trying to do with this line: context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( "update collection set CurrencyID = 1 ); previously i'm seeding the database with Dollar currency

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved, here are enumerated by order the steps i followed:

1. Change the foreign key property mapping to Not Required
2. Seed only the primary key values
3. Update-Database
4. Change back the property to Required
5. Add new migration and seed the values for foreign key column
6. Update-Database