# Add field and assign value to all existing records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following migration I am trying to apply:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus",
        c => new
            {
                QuoteRoHSStatusID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Status = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.QuoteRoHSStatusID)
        .Index(t => t.Status, unique: true, name: "IX_RoHSStatusIndex");

    AddColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    CreateIndex("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", "dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", cascadeDelete: true);
    DropColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "RoHS");
}
```

When I run `update-database`, I get the following error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.tblQuoteGeneral_dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus_QuoteRoHSStatusID".
>   The conflict occurred in database "WebPDC", table
>   "dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus", column 'QuoteRoHSStatusID'.

I do have existing records in `tblQuoteGeneral`. So, I need to assign a value (`3`) to `QuoteRoHSStatusID` for all existing records. I have tried the following modification to the auto generated migration shown above:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus",
        c => new
        {
            QuoteRoHSStatusID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Status = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
        })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.QuoteRoHSStatusID)
        .Index(t => t.Status, unique: true, name: "IX_RoHSStatusIndex");

    AddColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", c => c.Int(nullable: true));
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.tblQuoteGeneral SET QuoteRoHSStatusID = 3");
    AlterColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

    CreateIndex("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", "dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", cascadeDelete: true);
    DropColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "RoHS");
}
```

I am still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I would like to accomplish the above in one migration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665416/ef-6-code-based-migration-add-not-null-property-to-existing-entity

Comment: **@E-Bat**, thanks for point me to that question. I already knew I could split the migration apart. I was looking for a way to do it in one migration. I have answered my own question showing how it can be done in one migration.

Comment: Oh I missed the Edit you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. I'll post it just for anyone else that may find it useful. I did everything right in my modification to the auto generated migration except for populating the `pltblQuoteRoHSStatus` table with values. How can I run `UPDATE dbo.tblQuoteGeneral SET QuoteRoHSStatusID = 3` without already having a record in `pltblQuoteRoHSStatus` with a `ID` of `3`. That is what was causing the error due to the foreign key constraint.

So, here is my working code:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus",
        c => new
        {
            QuoteRoHSStatusID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Status = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
        })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.QuoteRoHSStatusID)
        .Index(t => t.Status, unique: true, name: "IX_RoHSStatusIndex");

    AddColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", c => c.Int(nullable: true));
    Sql("INSERT INTO dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus (Status) VALUES ('Compliant') ");
    Sql("INSERT INTO dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus (Status) VALUES ('Noncompliant') ");
    Sql("INSERT INTO dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus (Status) VALUES ('Unknown') ");
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.tblQuoteGeneral SET QuoteRoHSStatusID = 3");
    AlterColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

    CreateIndex("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", "dbo.pltblQuoteRoHSStatus", "QuoteRoHSStatusID", cascadeDelete: true);
    DropColumn("dbo.tblQuoteGeneral", "RoHS");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two migrations:

In the first, you add the field with the (nullable) foreign key.  Apply that migration to the database, then update the field in the database with a script.

Then add your second migration to make the field non-nullable.

Comment: That is the approach I have taken in the past. I thought there would/should be a way to do it in one migration. Can I not do it in one migration?

Comment: I don't believe so, no.

Comment: you can do it all in one migration. I figured out what I was doing wrong and posted it as an answer. I up-voted your answer, since it will work and I have broke it into 2 separate migrations in the past.